# floor heating from the basement ceiling

Tags: flooring, heating, floorheating

After I installed my mini split with a heat pump in my city rowhouse in the Midlantic region last winter, I noticed that the hot air from the wall mounted heads were not warming the floor on the first floor.  I could turn on the heat from the basement, but that would be a waste and terribly inefficient.  As I see it I have three options - really two as I don't want to lose room space with baseboard heaters. I have complete access to the wooden original floor from underneath in the basement.  I was thinking hydronic but was wondering if I would get a real return on heating a floor that is only like 250 sqft.  I do have a natural gas tankless water heater but looking at a recirculating pump etc.. I don't know. The other option would be using wire-based electric system underneath would be easier but the common knowledge says electricity is more expensive-but is it that more expensive?  My understanding is that the larger the floor the smaller the cost per sqft because the equipment cost are diminishing.

My dilemma is that @ 250 sqft would hydronic really pay off in the long or even short run or would it make more sense to go with the electric. I would like to get working on this project and need to start planning one way or the other.

Thanks in advance for any feedback/input.

Comment: I think you meant [hydronic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydronics), not [hydroponic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydroponics). There's a critical difference. Unless, of course, you're growing vegetables in your heating system. ;)

Comment: haha - thanks I will make the edits.

Answer (score 1):

I'd venture to guess that turning on the basement heat pump at 300+% efficiency would beat running electric resistance heat at 100% efficiency, and requires no additional install expense.

Answer (score 0):

There's also the solution of simply insulating the basement ceiling. Note that this won't have much effect on your energy use, but will keep the floor a bit closer to the living-space temperatures.

Older and cheaper solutions: Rugs and slippers.